# Power BI - can there be custom connector settings

Tags: powerbi

Can there be Custom connector settings?

Let's say we have a QA and a PROD system running odata queries.

We have different AuthorizeUrl and TokenUrl for those systems.

In a case like this, would I be making two separate connectors with urls hardcoded?

I haven't figured out the point of the LoadFromResource /

Extension.Contents mechanism.  Is there a way those settings would be configured by the user?

When testing a custom connector I just deploy a .mez file to the "Custom Connectors" folder.

I don't deploy a "token_url" text file there.  If I unzipped the .mez file I'd see that.  Just wondering is there any way those values are changed by a user or how do people usually deal with this sort of thing?

Similarly, we have a TenantID guid that might be nice to save / cache.